# Microsoft.EntityFrameworkCore.ChangeTracking.EntityEntry

Tags: c#, asp.net, .net-core, entity-framework-core

I am facing error for method below:

```
    internal class OracleRepository<TDbContext, TEntity> : IQueryRepository<TEntity>
            where TDbContext : DbContext
            where TEntity : class
        {
            private readonly TDbContext _dbContext;
            private readonly Func<TDbContext, DbSet<TEntity>> _selector;
            private readonly ILogger<OracleRepository<TDbContext, TEntity>> _logger;
    
            public OracleRepository(
                TDbContext dbContext,
                Func<TDbContext, DbSet<TEntity>> selector, ILogger<OracleRepository<TDbContext, TEntity>> logger)
            {
                _dbContext = dbContext;
                _selector = selector;
                _logger = logger;
            }
```

Error at this method:

```
public  async Task<TEntity> Insert(TEntity value) => await Task.Run(() => _selector(_dbContext).Add(value));
```

were _selector is Function.

Comment: After adding this still same mictosoft.entityframework core,changing issue  public async Task<TEntity> Insert(TEntity value) => await _selector(_dbContext).AddAsync(value);

Comment: What error do you get?

Comment: Microsoft.EntityFrameworkCore.ChangeTracking.EntityEntry

Comment: `Microsoft.EntityFrameworkCore.ChangeTracking.EntityEntry` is a name of a class. The error must show some message, this is what we are asking for.

Comment: Cannot implicity convert type 'Microsoft.entityframeworkcore.Changtracking.EntityEntry<TEntity>'to TEntity

Comment: Show usage. At least await and Task.Run is weird. Also useless generic repository pattern.

Comment: Ok, so that's the error which is bothering you. Look at the `Add` / `AddAsync` method definitions - they return tracking entry instance, not the entity (which btw is the same passed to them - your `value` variable). So either add `return value;` after the call to `Add` / `AddAsync`, or use the `Entity` property of the result, e.g. `=> (await _selector(_dbContext).AddAsync(value)).Entity;`

Comment: public  async Task<TEntity> Insert(TEntity value) => await  _selector(_dbContext).Add(value)).Entity; tried with i am getting Tentity Getawaiter does not econtain definition and no accessible

Comment: public  async Task<TEntity> Insert(TEntity value) => await  _selector(_dbContext).AddAsync(value)).Entity; even tried with addAsync still i have Entityentry issue

Comment: You are missing `(` before `await`. Please look at the example in my previous comment.